# How Google can check whether an application is installed from Play Store or Not?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, google-play-games

If a developer turns ON Google Play's [Anti-Piracy setup](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/antipiracy), the application cannot access the play services if it is not installed from Play Store(so says Google). My question is how Google verifies this? More than that I need to know, if I can install an application from the play store, then modify the apk and then re-installs it in my phone manually(by enabling 'install from unknown sources') AND then use the play services?

Answer (score 1):

i think following link can explain how google Play knows or in fact how any dev can know if a given app was installed from play store or side loaded:

[How to know an application is installed from google play or side-load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809438/how-to-know-an-application-is-installed-from-google-play-or-side-load)